# pytest configuration problem (transition from nosetests (71 sec) to pytest (1536 sec))

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

The problem:

**pytest** (decided by policy) takes 1536 seconds to run the same test suite (585 tests) as **nosetest**, which runs in 71 seconds.

The `pytest.ini` files is:

```
[pytest]
python_files = tests_*.py *_tests.py
norecursedirs = .idea  (pycharm env).
testpaths = tests
```

And the file is placed at the root of the project:

```
root
 |-+ mod1
 | |-- core.py
 | |-- utils.py
 |-+ mod2
 | |-- core.py
 | |-- utils2.py
 |-+ tests
 | |-- test_mod1
 | |-- test_mod2
 |-+ utils (don't test).
 | |-- u1.py
 | |-- u2.py
 |- pytest.ini
 |- readme.md
```

Things I've checked (following advice from the 14 other SO posts):

- The number of Pass/Fails is the same.
- When running the tests individually with pytests they take ~ 20ms.
- When running the folder with pytests 10-20 tests take 14-15 seconds.
- The test suite has one environment, there's no env or os magic. Just lots of technical logic.
- Each test_xyz.py file has it's own isolated `def setup` and `def teardown` that creates/drop an sqlite database. The tests interact with the database, by adding new transactions and checking the additions. Example:

```py
global db

def setup():
   db = get_new_db()

def teardown():
   pass

def test_01():
   w = Widget(db)  # create widget instance.
   w.add_friend('a@b.com')
   assert 'a@b.com' in w.friends()
```

Questions:

1. Do I really have to plaster @pytest.fixtures(scope='module') on the `setup` and `teardown` of every 585 tests? I hope not.
2. What can I do to get the runtime of `pytest` to be similar to `nosetests`?

Comment: Can you give an example layout of a test module (w/o the impl)? You may need to rename the `def setup()`/`def teardown()` to smth like `def setup_module()`/`def teardown_module()`, depending on the fixture scope (which is not any better than passing the `pytest.fixture` decorator, unfortunately)

Comment: example layout added.

Comment: I'm afraid, you'll need to rename the setup/teardown functions; `pytest` and `nose` run them with different scope. You batch rename them in all tests via smth like `grep -lr "\(def setup():\|def teardown():\)" | xargs sed -i 's/def setup():/def setup_module():/g;s/def teardown():/def teardown_module():/g'`

Comment: I think this is the answer. Could you convert it to an answer please and I can tick it off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why `pytest` chose to invoke the module setup function in a `pytest_runtest_setup` hook that runs once per each test instead of a module-scoped autouse fixture, but [here it is](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/8ffa3aa65dcb10fee7ab0ffe7508cad7386ce9ce/src/_pytest/nose.py#L35):

```py
@hookimpl(trylast=True)
def pytest_runtest_setup(item):
    if is_potential_nosetest(item):
        if not call_optional(item.obj, "setup"):
            # call module level setup if there is no object level one
            call_optional(item.parent.obj, "setup")
        # XXX this implies we only call teardown when setup worked
        item.session._setupstate.addfinalizer((lambda: teardown_nose(item)), item)
```

This means you'll need to rename the setup/teardown functions to `setup_module()`/`teardown_module()`. If you're on Linux/MacOS, you can use `sed` combined with `grep` for batch renaming:

```
$ grep -lr "\(def setup():\|def teardown():\)" | \
  xargs sed -i 's/def setup():/def setup_module():/g;s/def teardown():/def teardown_module():/g'
```