# pytest strange behavior with setup() function

Tags: pytest

I observe the implicit behavior of pytest when calling a function called setup().

```
import pytest

def config():
    login = 'John'
    password = '123'
    env = 'staging'
    return login, password, env

def setup(conf_func):
    return [conf_func()]

@pytest.mark.parametrize('login, password, env', setup(config))
def test_func(login, password, env):
    print(login, password, env)
    assert False
```

If run pytest for code above it returns strange error:

```
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.6.8, pytest-5.0.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.12.0
rootdir: C:\python\experiments\fixtures
collected 1 item

test_fix6.py E
test setup failed
cls = <class '_pytest.runner.CallInfo'>
func = <function call_runtest_hook.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x0000000003AA6B70>
when = 'setup'
reraise = (<class '_pytest.outcomes.Exit'>, <class 'KeyboardInterrupt'>)

    @classmethod
    def from_call(cls, func, when, reraise=None):
        #: context of invocation: one of "setup", "call",
        #: "teardown", "memocollect"
        start = time()
        excinfo = None
        try:
>           result = func()

venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py:220: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py:192: in <lambda>
    lambda: ihook(item=item, **kwds), when=when, reraise=reraise
venv\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py:289: in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
venv\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py:87: in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
venv\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py:81: in <lambda>
    firstresult=hook.spec.opts.get("firstresult") if hook.spec else False,
venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\nose.py:34: in pytest_runtest_setup
    call_optional(item.parent.obj, "setup")
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
```

I know that pytest supports x-unit style but I did not find any mention of setup() function in the pytest documentation. If I change function name (for example setup_func()) it works normally.

Can anyone explain why such strange behavior occurs and what other function names are incompatible with pytest?

Comment: This is indeed not mentioned anywhere in the docs AFAIK, but `pytest` treats `setup`/`teardown` functions as function-scoped setup/teardown. See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55977071/2650249) for code reference.

Answer (score -1):

The `setup` function actually comes from [nose testing framework](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which is integrated in pytest. More information you can find [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/nose.html)